# Create a cron job for age calculation

Tags: php, laravel-5, cron

I have created a cronjob for age calculation named "cronAge" using command

```
php artisan make:command cronAge
```

Below is my Employee Model:

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'tag_no';    
    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $fillable = [        
        'tag_no',
        'emp_type', 
        'age',            
        'date_of_birth',                   
    ];  
}
```

I am planning to call the cronjob monthly.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
       $schedule->command('cronAge')
                 ->monthly();
    }
```

This is my function: Its not a working code. It only shows the logic for calculating the age.

```
public function handle()
    {
        $emp= new Employee();
        $today = new Date();
        $birth_day = $emp->date_of_birth;
        if ($today.getFullYear() - $birth_day.getFullYear() == 1) {
            if ($today.getMonth() == $birth_day.getMonth()
               && $today.getDate() == $birth_day.getDate()) {            
                $emp->age = $emp->age+1;
            }
        }
    }
```

So how to implement my logic in the function. Is the logic rite? And please help me in this. I'm new to this cronjob topic and i donno much.

Comment: There's absolutely no need to store ages in your database. If it already contains birth dates, then ages can be calculated instantaneously from those whenever you need them. If you store both, then you're making it more likely that your database will contain inconsistent data. [Here's a link to Wikipedia's page on database normalization.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: ohhhh thanks for the suggestion :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The best way is to use the Carbon library to parse the date_of_birth field to calculate age. The code is given below.

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'tag_no';    
    public $incrementing = false;    
    protected $fillable = [        
        'tag_no',
        'emp_type',        
        'date_of_birth',         
    ]; 

    public function getAgeAttribute()
    {
        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['date_of_birth'])->age; 
    }

}
```

We don't need the age field in the table as well. We can just find age using the Carbon library.

And if `$emp` is the variable passed to your **view.blade.php** , then the age can be displayed using just :

```
{{ $emp->age }}
```

This way it can be done.